# Is Android's SQLiteStatement (prepared statement) thread-safe? I.e. is "bind*, bind*... execute" atomic?

Tags: sql, android, concurrency, thread-safety, prepared-statement

I'm wondering whether prepared statements in Android (instances of SQLiteStatement) are thread-safe. In particular I'm asking with regard to the following scenario:

In a ContentProvider you create a pre-compiled insert statement during onCreate. Then, in the overriden insert method you make use of this statement by binding a set of parameters to it and calling executeInsert on it.

We know that a ContentProvider has to be written in a thread-safe manner. If SQLiteStatement does not bind parameters per thread, a concurrent call to the provider's insert method would alter the statement's bindings and result in unpredictable behavior.

Android's own Contacts provider uses prepared statements in this way (http://bit.ly/bDuKAT), so I tend to believe that they are in fact thread-safe.  Looking at the source code of SQLiteStatement I don't see how though (http://bit.ly/9M1Swv).

So, is SQLiteStatement (or SQLiteProgram that is) thread-safe with respect to parameter binding or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is explicitly stated in [the SQLiteStatement documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html) that

> SQLiteStatement is not internally synchronized

Thus, the class is not thread-safe and cannot be used by multiple threads concurrently without unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

If it's two separate methods, then it can't possibly be thread-safe:

```
mStatusUpdateDelete.bindLong(1, dataId);
mStatusUpdateDelete.execute();
```

The first thread could call `bindLong` with 1, then the second thread with 2, and then both threads could call `execute`. So even if `bindLong` and `execute` *internally* are thread safe, it wouldn't help.

Comment: That's generally the case, yes.  However, it could still be thread-safe if SQLiteStatement's structure in which the binding is kept is of type ThreadLocal<?>.  In this case SQLiteStatement would have a per-thread binding.  In the particular case of SQLiteStatement all parameter binding is delegated to a native SQLite interface of which I don't know the inner workings.  If it is not thread-safe (of which we are both pretty sure), I wonder how the Contacts provider deals with this issue.